# Codepipeline ARN not available through Terraform but available in metadata using cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sns, aws-codepipeline, aws-codestar

Executing AWS cli command as below:

`aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name pipeline_name`

produces following output

```
{
    "pipeline": {
        "name": "xxxxx",,
        "roleArn": "xxxxx",,
        "artifactStore": {
            "type": "S3",
            "location": "xxxxx",
        },
        "stages": [
            {
                "name": "Source",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "Source",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Source",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "CodeCommit",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "BranchName": "main",
                            "PollForSourceChanges": "true",
                            "RepositoryName": "xxxxx",
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceOutput"
                            }
                        ],
                        "inputArtifacts": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Build",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "Build",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Build",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "CodeBuild",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "ProjectName": "xxxxx",
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "BuildOutput"
                            }
                        ],
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceOutput"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Deploy",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "Deploy",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Deploy",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "CodeDeployToECS",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "AppSpecTemplateArtifact": "BuildOutput",
                            "AppSpecTemplatePath": "appspec.yml",
                            "ApplicationName": "xxxxx",
                            "DeploymentGroupName": "xxxxx",
                            "Image1ArtifactName": "BuildOutput",
                            "Image1ContainerName": "IMAGE1_NAME",
                            "TaskDefinitionTemplateArtifact": "BuildOutput",
                            "TaskDefinitionTemplatePath": "taskdef.json"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [],
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "BuildOutput"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "version": 3
    },
    "metadata": {
        "pipelineArn": "xxxxx",
        "created": "xxxxx",
        "updated": "xxxxx",
    }
}
```

We can see that metadata field has  `"pipelineArn": "xxxxx",` . But this arn is not available in console nor have I been able to find any Terraform data source for this.

Is it possible to retrieve codepipline ARN in Terraform?

Also, to clarify I need this for `"aws_codestarnotifications_notification_rule"` where resource arn is required.

Comment: Is CodePipeline also created with Terraform?

Comment: yes, it is created with terraform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ARN for the CodePipeline is available in the AWS console, but it is a bit hard to find. If you go to `Pipelines -> Choose any pipeline -> Settings` it is in the `General` tab, under `Pipeline ARN` (1).

[image]

As for the getting the CodePipeline ARN through Terraform, that is possible by getting the attribute with the same name after the CodePipeline resource is created (2). So in case the CodePipline was not created with Terraform, you can hard-code the value. If it was, you could simply reference the output attribute in the `"aws_codestarnotifications_notification_rule"` resource:

```
resource "aws_codestarnotifications_notification_rule" "this" {
  detail_type    = ""
  event_type_ids = [""]

  name     = ""
  resource = aws_codepipeline.this.arn

  target {
    address = ...
  }
}
```

This code snippet assumes that you will fill out other details and that there is a Terraform code block which creates a CodePipeline resource with name this, i.e., you would have to have a code block similar to following:

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "this" {
...
}
```

---

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-view-console.html#pipelines-settings-console
2. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/codepipeline#arn

Comment: Thanks @Marko for the reply. Codepipeline has been created with Terraform.

What is intriguing is that unlike codecommit repositories which we can get as data resource, codepipeline doesn't seem to follow that convention. Is there any specific reason as to why code pipeline has been treated differently? At the end of day, codepipeline is also a resource and if it is possible to gets its metadata from command line, so should be through some terraform filter or data source.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't got a response for you. That might be a good question to ask someone from AWS. :)